# Reconstruct file from diff

Tags: diff

Say I have a file `foo` and a file `bar`. I now call the following commands:

```
$ diff foo bar > diff_foobar
$ rm bar
```

Is there a(n easy) way to programmatically reconstruct the missing `bar` from `foo` and `diff_foobar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you apply the patch:

You did:

```
$ diff foo bar > diff_foobar
$ rm bar
```

Now do:

```
$ patch  foo -o bar < diff_foobar
```

Answer (score 5):

Reconstructing files from diffs, also known as "applying diffs", is what
utility `patch` does:

```bsh
## Create two arbitrary files, `original' and `altered':
$ seq 0 3 >original
$ seq 7 11 >altered

## Compute a diff from `original' to `altered':
$ diff original altered >diff

## Copy `original' before patching it
$ cp -vi original original.0
`original' -> `original.0'
$ patch <diff original # This modifies `original'!
patching file original

## Confirm that we rebuilt the file from `original' and `diff`
$ diff --report-identical-files original altered
Files original and altered are identical
```

The patch command also has a bunch of options, in particular to apply
patches in reverse.

Comment: Note that `diff` has two output modes, controlled by options: human readable and machine readable, e.g. `patch`.

Comment: @waltinator: Indeed. I tried to make my answer rather minimal, but it is true that so-called unified diffs are common when patching is intended. (I personally find them quite human-readable as well.)